# How many websockets can client receive per second?

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets, websocket, flooding

I have simple javascript websocket on client side

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://myhost:myport");
ws.onopen = function(e) {
    // handle sockets here
};
```

I am going to write C++ server that might send 10,000-100,000 sockets to client per second.
**Question**: is it good performance for websockets? Will it work fine without delays? What is the limit number of sockets I can send without delays?

Comment: I don´t think you´re sending sockets around. And nothing is "without delay", but 100K messages per second and client (or sockets or whatever) isn´t good at all

Comment: What exactly are you using that requires 100k sockets per second? Just curious :)